# Is there a way to update the text of the previous line in a console application running in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, terminal

```
    @Test
    fun updateLastLine() {
        System.out.print("First Text")
        System.out.print("\rSecond Text")
        System.out.print("\n")
        // Console Output (already working as intended)
        // Second Text
    }

    @Test
    fun updatePreviousLineWithCarriageReturn() {
        System.out.print("Actual Update\n")
        System.out.print("Last Line\n")
        System.out.print("\rExpected Update")
        System.out.print("\n")
        // Console Output (Expected)
        // Expected Update
        // Last Line

        // Console Output (Actual)
        // Actual Update
        // Last Line
        // Expected Update
    }

    @Test
    fun updatePreviousLineWithBackSpace() {
        System.out.print("Actual Update\n")
        System.out.print("Last Line\n")
        System.out.print("\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bExpected Update")
        System.out.print("\n")
        // equal updatePreviousLineWithCarriageReturn
    }
```

I am using the terminal within Intelllj Community,

I could update the last line of text printed to the console using a carriage return.

However, the previous text that was moved to the next line using \n could not be modified in any way.

I couldn't find a reference that explained how to fix the old text after jumping to a new line.

Is there any way to change the text of the previous line?

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no proper solution for this, because kotlin is cross platform. clearing the console or editing the last output has ever been a problem with consoles because they are different on each system and even emulator. But if you stay e.g. on linux there are clear solutions.

Comment: Don't print the line out until you've finished with it -- store it in a variable until then, where it can be updated safely.